# How can I docking Comment box to a table?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a PivotTable that has related Comment box.
PivotTable moves with a macro in container sheet when an event happens.

I want docking whose Comment box to move with PivotTable and state in constant related new position same as last.

How can I do that?

Are there any what to grouping and docking Comment box and its appropriate object (here is pivot table)?

Comment: try this [link](http://www.contextures.com/xlcomments03.html) to get you started

Comment: Above link is awsome, but I cant find answer of my question.